# Inter-process communication using Events c++

Tags: multithreading, winapi, createfile

I need to work with file using `CreateFile()` and `CreateEventEx()` functions.
For example,i open two instance of my programm,in first i open or create a file,in second i give a command `CloseHandle`,which i created in first instance.Help,how to implement this.

Comment: There is no `CreateEventEx()` function in the Win32 API, only `CreateEvent()`. In any case, the second instance of your app cannot close the handle in the first instance. The first instance must close its own handle. The second instance can signal an event to notify the first instance that it wants the handle to be closed, but the first instance needs to be looking for that signal.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why no?There is [CreateEventEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function,which i exactly must to use,not `CreateEvent()`. How to implement your advice?

Comment: When I searched MSDN earlier, I could not find any mention of a `CreateEventEx()` function. So apparently it is new in Vista+, and MSDN search is broken (not surprising - it does not always find everything). Now I see it, but it still does not change what I said earlier. An event is just a signal, the first instance of the app still has to recognize the signal and close its own handle to the file.